# Ubuntu pgAdmin 4 задать логин/пароль по умолчанию

Tags: python, ubuntu, postgresql, auth, pgadmin4

Устанавливаю `pgAdmin4` таким образом

```
> wget --directory-prefix=${VENV} https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v3.4/pip/pgadmin4-3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
> ${VENV}/bin/python -m pip install wheel
> ${VENV}/bin/python -m pip install ${VENV}/pgadmin4-3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

Все замечательно ставится, спрашивается логин и пароль

Как сделать так, чтоб логин и пароль не спрашивались, а ставились как конкретные строки?

Исходя из [этой документации](https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v4.11/docs/pgadmin4-4.11.pdf), попробовал так:

```
> export PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=$LOGIN
> export PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=$PASSWORD
```

Не помогло, оно все равно спрашивает логин/пароль

Надо что-то еще указать в конфигурационных файлах, например в `${VENV}/lib/${PYTHON}/site-packages/pgadmin4/config_local.py` как-то это прописать

Посмотрел [здесь](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/config_py.html) и попробовал в нем прописать

```
MAIL_USERNAME = LOGIN # Значение логина
MAIL_PASSWORD = PASSWORD # Значение пароля
```

Тоже не помогло

Как правильно сделать - что-то не нашел, видимо гуглить не умею

Подскажите, пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Порылся в исходниках

В файле `${VENV}/lib/${PYTHON}/site-packages/pgadmin4/pgadmin/setup/user_info.py` нашел это:

```
if all(value in os.environ for value in ['PGADMIN_SETUP_EMAIL', 'PGADMIN_SETUP_PASSWORD']):
   email = ''
   p1 = ''
   if os.environ['PGADMIN_SETUP_EMAIL'] and os.environ['PGADMIN_SETUP_PASSWORD']:
       email = os.environ['PGADMIN_SETUP_EMAIL']
       p1 = os.environ['PGADMIN_SETUP_PASSWORD']
   else:
       # Prompt the user for their default username and password.
       .
       .
       .
       .
```

Отсюда понятно, что переменные среды нужно ставить не те, которые в мануале, а следующие:

```
export PGADMIN_SETUP_EMAIL=$LOGIN
export PGADMIN_SETUP_PASSWORD=$PASSWORD
```

Сделал так - все получилось